# How can I lock Fragment rotation

Tags: android, android-fragments, qr-code

How can I lock one (and only one) Fragment to rotate on my tablet version ?

I'm using a Fragment lib for my qrcode scanner but I do not know why this one is rotating but don't adapte the camera view to the new view format :/

Edit: I use configChange to handle the rotation on others fragments.

Answer (score 0):

Override setUserVisibleHint() in each fragment.

In the portrait only fragments:

```
@Override
 public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
if(isVisibleToUser) {
    Activity a = getActivity();
    if(a != null) a.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
  }
}
```

in the the portrait/landscape fragment:`

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
if(isVisibleToUser) {
    Activity a = getActivity();
    if(a != null) a.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_FULL_SENSOR);
}
}
```

This will allow the whole activity to rotate in one fragment, but fix it to portrait in others.